# Passing variable from bash-python-bash

Tags: python, bash, variables, ubuntu

To use logarithmic function, I used export to pass a variable `$var1` from bash to python script. After the calculation, I used

```
  os.environ['var1']=str(result)
```

to send the result back to bash script.
However, the bash still shows the unmodified value.

Comment: That is probably because the change of the environment variable in the child process doesn't affect the parent shell?

Comment: your best choice is to `print result` and capture Python's output in bash.

Comment: Actually it all depends how your scripts work. Does your bash script waits for your python script to finish ? Or do you launch them separately ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have a look at the `os.putenv(key, value)` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.putenv) maybe it could help you.
Although as noted on the doc :

> When putenv() is supported, assignments to items in os.environ are automatically translated into corresponding calls to putenv(); however, calls to putenv() don’t update os.environ, so it is actually preferable to assign to items of os.environ.

EDIT :
moooeeeep thought about it just a minute before me, but the variable you change only applies to the current process. In such a case I can see two solutions :
 - Write the data to a file and read it with your bash script
 - Call your bash script directly from within python so that the bash process would inherit your modified variable.

Comment: it's still giving the same result.

Comment: Did you put that code in a `try: [...] except: [...]` statement ? Maybe there is an error when setting the env variable and you are not aware of it because of your block catching every exception.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if you can modify such a variable. Because it changes it for the current process and not for the father process. It may be a good idea to write the data to a file and read it in the bash script.